# What timezone does Amazon's "Kindle book release" follow?

Tags: amazon, kindle

I'm trying to buy a book that goes on-sale tomorrow.

Does the sale start at midnight where I live or does it start at midnight PDT where Amazon HQ is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindle books are released based on Pacific Standard Time, where Amazon is primarily based.

Comment: Is this the same as Pacific Daylight Saving Time (Daylight Saving Time)?

Comment: There is no daylight saving time in December.